# Link State Routing Implementation

Tags: algorithm, networking, routes

I 'm implementing a Link State Routing Protocol and I have some doubts.
First of all, let me say that I am using a simple library that provides me the network topology, a router Class (that doesn't obviously provide me the routing protocol), and message Class.

My goal is to implement 2 classes: one that (given the topology of the network) builds a routing table (neighbor discovering and Dijkstra), and another that extends class Message of the library and implements represent the messages exchanged by the routers.

In particular, my doubts are:

- How can a router discover all its neighbors?
- What will be the structure of a message exchanged by routers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which link state routing protocol are you implementing? Ospf? Or are you intending to design a new protocol which you will then implement?

Answer (score 0):

In general a hello mechanism is used to discover neighbors, possibly coupled with authentication.

The message format (and number and type of messages) depends on the design of the protocol.

I would recommend doing some research on how ospf handles these points, then you may be able to refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, once a router is on, it will send out Hello packet through all of its interfaces introducing itself. This packet contains basic information about the router which is useful for building the adjacency with its neighbors. Different routing protocols use different format of Hello packet.

OSPF includes network mask in its Hello packet. A neighbor router that receives this packet and has same network mask will agree to start building the adjacency so the communication can go further.

Differently, EIGRP only allows a router to build the adjacency with neighbor routers which have the same autonomous system number in the hello packets it receives.

After this phase, the two routers will then be able to exchange their routing information.